# How to blur part of the screen in the game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks, opengl, blur

I'm making an FPS game, and for some of my guns, i want to be able to zoom in so that i can see farther. This isn't the problem. What i really want is to make the rest of the screen (The part not looking through the scope) blurry so that it looks like the character is focusing through the scope.

I want everything that is not seen directly through the scope to be blurred, for example, refer to the scopes of Crysis 3.

Comment: You can use a 2Dfilter to accomplish this. Probably also with a  few custom uniforms so you can pass the information to the shader about when and where to blur.

Comment: Are you looking to simulate DOF (Depth of Field), or do you specifically want to blur everything not in scope, by the same factor, regardless of distance from focus point?

Comment: Does [**this**](http://solarlune-gameup.blogspot.com/2011/02/opengl-2d-screen-filters-in-bge-part-2.html) help at all?

Comment: @GoranMilovanovic I want to blur everything not in the scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the sample shader linked by @NoviceInDisguise:

How it works: the shader gets the rendered image as a texture its x/y coordinates range from 0 to 1.0

The distance from center is calculated by `sqrt(x*x+y*y) > .3` to exclude a circular region from blur.

```
uniform sampler2D bgl_RenderedTexture;

void main(void)
{
  vec4 texcolor = texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
  float x =  gl_TexCoord[0].st.x - .5;
  float y =  gl_TexCoord[0].st.y - .5;   

  if ( sqrt(x*x+y*y) > .3 ) { 
       float value = 0.0015;
       vec4 color = texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].st.x + value, gl_TexCoord[0].st.y + value)); // Sample area around current pixel
       color += texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].st.x - value, gl_TexCoord[0].st.y - value));
       color += texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].st.x + value, gl_TexCoord[0].st.y - value));
       color += texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].st.x - value, gl_TexCoord[0].st.y + value));
       color /= 4.0;        
       gl_FragColor = color;
   }
   else {
       gl_FragColor =texcolor;
   }
}
```

[image]

Node setup: Add a Filter 2D configure it as *Custom Shader* and select the above script.

[image]
Sample render

Disclaimer: A decent blur needs to incorporate values from a 3x3, 5x5 or bigger matrix, the sample code only uses the left and right neighbor.

Comment: Gosh this was a while back, sorry for not confirming your answer yet :/   Is the float value the blur amount? And how would I incorporate a matrix?